# How to get permissions to create a file/directory with node fs

Tags: node.js, operating-system, filesystems, electron

When running the following in my packaged electron app:

`fs.mkdirSync('myNewDirectory');`

I keep getting `EACCES: permission denied, mkdir`.

This doesn't happen when I'm in dev mode. It only happens after I package and run the app.

How do I get the appropriate permissions to create a directory, or even a file, in a packaged electron app?

Comment: first, Try to run your app as root (sudo node YOUR_APP). the problem still there ?

Comment: i can't seem to figure out how to do this. My app is called SetManager, so when I do `sudo node SetManager.app` it fails saying `cannot find module`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mkdirSync` will attempt to create myNewDirectory relative to the current working directory. Try setting the absolute path, perhaps using `__dirname`.

Comment: Saved me too! Best solution.

Comment: This still gives me an error: EROFS Error Read-only file system.